# How to add 2 data from dynamic table?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Please help me, im new at jquery, i want to find a cumulative from column a 
and b, then the cumulative value from two column will be added. 
[image of output and the way it would be dispalyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZFfJ.png)

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function addRow(tableID) {

   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

   var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

   for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
     case "text":
       newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
       break;
     case "checkbox":
       newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
       break;
     case "select-one":
       newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
       break;
    }
   }
  }

  function deleteRow(tableID) {
   try {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;

   for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
     if(rowCount <= 1) {
      alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
      break;
     }
     table.deleteRow(i);
     rowCount--;
     i--;
    }


   }
   }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
   }
  }
  function findTotal(){
   var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
   var tot=0;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
     tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }
   document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  }
  function findTotalAmount(){
   var arr = document.getElementsByName('amount');
   var totamount=0;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
     totamount += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }
   document.getElementById('totalamount').value = totamount;
  }
  
  
  $(document).ready(function(e){
  $("input").change(function(){
   var toplam=0;
   $("input[name=total]").each(function(){
    toplam = toplam + parseInt($(this).val());
   })
   $("input[name=toplam_gider]").val(toplam);
  });
});
 </SCRIPT>
```

```html
<BODY>
<HTML>
 



 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="640" border="1">
  <TR>
   <TD width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
   <TD width="283"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="qty" value="0"/></TD>
   <TD width="124"><input type="text" onblur="findTotalAmount()" name="amount" value="0"/></TD>
   <td width="74"><input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /></td>
   <td width="105"><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /></td>
  </TR>
  
 </TABLE>
 <br /> 
 GST Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"  value="0"/> <br />
 Total Amount: <input type="text" name="total" id="totalamount"  value="0"/><br />
 Grand Total: <input type="text" name="toplam_gider" />

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do? It is not clear what you need help with.

Comment: I want to add the value from a column which are dynamically generate. I have two column, and then the cumulative value from two column will be added together..as in the attached picture

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean adding every value from a colum then adding them together?

You can travel through your table with the JQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

```js
$(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<$('table tr:nth-of-type(1) td').length;i++){
    var columnTotal = 0;
    $('table tr td:nth-of-type('+(i+1)+')').each(function(){
      columnTotal+=+$(this).text();
    });
    
    $('body').append('<p>Total column '+(i+1)+' = <span class="subtotal">'+columnTotal+'</span></p>');
  }
  
  var totalTotal=0;
  $('.subtotal').each(function(){
    totalTotal+=+$(this).text();
  });
  $('body').append('<p class="total">Total total = '+totalTotal+'</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>524</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you adjust my coding, because i find it a little difficult when it it in dynamic table and when it delete the row it will automatically adjust the total  value

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Try to adapt your method with my solution.

Comment: Could you put an example with the concept of dynamic table which calculate input from user? sorry im kind of new at this